# Charging Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, charge

Is it possible to use the leakage current from many capacitors to recharge another capacitor or decrease the leakage current in another capacitor?

Comment: Q=CV ring any bells?

Comment: Be very clear about what you mean by the leakage current - some folk may assume that you mean the untouchable internal leakage current due to non-perfect dielectrics.

Comment: yeah current leaking through dielectric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the leakage current from many capacitors to recharge another capacitor or decrease the leakage current in another capacitor?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2furNoC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Representation of a real capacitor with internal leakage.*

As Andy aka has pointed out, leakage current in a capacitor usually refers to current that flows or 'leaks' through the dielectric - the material that separates the conducting plates. The dielectric usually has an extremely high resistance but over time the capacitor will discharge through it.

Can you charge one capacitor from another? Yes.

Comment: thank you, though I assume that the leakage current is too low to really do anything to the capacitor.